# Spring's WebApplicationInitializer + servlet registration doesn't work on Apache Tomcat 8.0.32 on Debian

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I created extension of Spring's `AbstractContextLoaderInitializer` to register JSF servlet like this:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic facesServlet = servletContext.addServlet("facesServlet", new FacesServlet());
    facesServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    facesServlet.addMapping("*.xhtml");

    servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "Development");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", "true");

    servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "bootstrap");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic noCacheFilter = servletContext.addFilter("noCache", CacheControlFilter.class);
    noCacheFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "*.xhtml");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding",
            CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    characterEncodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic openEntityManagerInView = servletContext.addFilter("openEntityManagerInView",
            OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.class);
    openEntityManagerInView.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "*.xhtml");
}
```

This work just fine on Tomcat 7.0.55 (Windows) but the servlet is not initialized at all on Tomcat 8.0.32 (Debian).

Any ideas anyone ?

Thanks

Comment: Post more details such as stack trace, when this thing happens etc.

Comment: Did you try run Tomcat 8.0.32  on Windows? Does issue persist?

Comment: I cannot post any stack trace since this is not an exception. I just (normally) see in JSF being initialized in log. In this case I dont and any request to my mapped filed (.xhtml) fails. And this works just fine on Windows !

Answer (score 0):

Please check version of Java and environment variables. We had have a problem when moved from Java7 to Java8.

Comment: Hey, can u elaborate a bit ? What variables do u mean ? I see Tomcat using the correct java version...